# Calculate sum of i^2*C(n, i), 0 <= i <= n, 1 <= n <= 10^18

Tags: algorithm, combinations

Find the answer mod 1e9+7 in time limit 1 second.
C(n,i) equals the number of ways of choosing i items from n different items (ignoring the order).

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have thinking for hours, still don't know how to solve it. I know n is too big to use brute force, I try to infer formula, but fail.

Comment: If this is Project Euler problem, asking for solution is **ILLEGAL**.

Comment: Sorry, I encounter this problem in a local contest, don't know anything about Project Euler.

Comment: Are you sure you want the result modulo 10000000007 (which is 1e10 + 7)? It is popular to use (1e9 + 7) in these sorts of computations because the latter is a prime number.

Comment: sorry for the typo, its 1e9+7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a generating function, I believe you can show that the sum can be evaluated exactly as `n(n_2)*(2^(n-2))`.

This can be derived by rewriting the summation in the following form:

[image]

That summation can be simplified by recognizing it as just the binomial expansion of

[image]

which can be differentiated twice with respect to alpha, and evaluated at alpha=0, giving

[image]

We can check that this formula is giving the correct result with a simple Python script:

```
import numpy, scipy.misc

def fn(n):
    i = numpy.arange(0, n+1)
    combs = scipy.misc.comb(n, i)
    return numpy.sum((i**2) * combs)

def fn2(n):
    return n*(n+1) * (2 ** (n-2))


for n in range(1, 20):
    print('n={}, raw-sum={}, ratio={}' \
            .format(n, fn(n), (fn2(n) / fn(n))))
```

Which produces the following output:

```
n=1, raw-sum=1.0, ratio=1.0
n=2, raw-sum=6.0, ratio=1.0
n=3, raw-sum=24.0, ratio=1.0
n=4, raw-sum=80.0, ratio=1.0
n=5, raw-sum=240.0, ratio=1.0
n=6, raw-sum=672.0, ratio=1.0
n=7, raw-sum=1792.0, ratio=1.0
n=8, raw-sum=4608.0, ratio=1.0
n=9, raw-sum=11520.0, ratio=1.0
n=10, raw-sum=28160.0, ratio=1.0
n=11, raw-sum=67584.0, ratio=1.0
n=12, raw-sum=159744.0, ratio=1.0
n=13, raw-sum=372736.0, ratio=1.0
n=14, raw-sum=860160.0, ratio=1.0
n=15, raw-sum=1966080.0, ratio=1.0
n=16, raw-sum=4456448.0, ratio=1.0
n=17, raw-sum=10027008.0, ratio=1.0
n=18, raw-sum=22413312.0, ratio=1.0
n=19, raw-sum=49807360.0, ratio=1.0
```

It should then be a simple matter to compute your desired result modulo (1e9 + 7), making use of the [repeated squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) technique for computing 2^x, reducing all multiplications modulo (1e9 + 7) at each step of the calculation.

Comment: thank you very much.your analysis its elegant and clear. I seemed to understand a little bit, I know using the formula, the question can be solved in O(logn). However, my math is poor, I don't know how the generation function works. I should learn more math. thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Lucas can solve this question,I think the main code is lucas, you can learn lucas on the web site,it's easy to get the code.And after that,you can solve it as a easy question.

For example:

```
LL Lucas(LL a, LL b)
{
    if(a < mod && b < mod)
        return C(a, b);
    return
        C(a % mod, b % mod) * Lucas(a / mod, b / mod);
}
```

Here is a blog about lucas: https://blog.csdn.net/acdreamers/article/details/8037918

If you have any other question , you can reply under this.

I suggest learning the lucas algorithm , and you can get something.